# Setting mouse speed in Gnome just like in other desktop environments

Tags: gnome, x11

When I'm using XFCE I can set mouse pointer speed to "Acceleration: 5.0 | Sensitivity: 4 px". When I have to switch KDE I can use same settings because these are simply configuration tools for X11.

Gnome has sliders with no numbers. Different between Gnome 2.x and 3.x. Checking with xset also doesn't work because it gives different outputs without any change in Gnome settings.

Answer (score 2):

I think you're looking for the `xinput` command. On my Thinkpad laptop:

```
% xinput list
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Logitech USB Receiver                     id=9    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Logitech USB Receiver                     id=10   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad                id=12   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ TPPS/2 IBM TrackPoint                     id=13   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Sleep Button                              id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=11   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ ThinkPad Extra Buttons                    id=14   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

Looking at the properties for my pointing device (id=12):

```
% xinput list-props 12 | grep -i acc
    Device Accel Profile (249): 1
    Device Accel Constant Deceleration (250):   2.500000
    Device Accel Adaptive Deceleration (251):   1.000000
    Device Accel Velocity Scaling (252):    12.500000
```

You can read more about it here on the [Arch Linux Wiki - Mouse Acceleration topic](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Mouse_acceleration).